# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.input.reduce is not a function" in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i'm creating a very simple sum of Table of `Amount` by using `computed` in `vuejs`, but there is an issue come up

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.input.reduce is not a function"

Still, i cant figure it out with my code.

// My `Vue js`

```
<pre>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Current_id</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Modify</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(user,key) in users">
                    <td>{{ user.user.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.description }}</td>
                    <td>${{ user.amount }}</td>
                    <td @click.prevent="editUser(key)">
                        <span class="btn btn-info">Edit</span>
                    </td>
                    <td @click.prevent="remove(user.id)">
                        <span class="btn btn-danger">Delete</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Total of Amount {{ total }}</p>
    </div>  
</pre>
```

// My `Script` file

```
<pre>
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
            input: {
                date: "",
                description: "",
                amount: ""
            },
            edit: false,
            add: true,

        }
    },

    computed: {
        total() {
            return this.input.reduce((total, item) => {
                return total + item.amount;
            }, 0);
        }
    },
</pre>
```

Any Help? Thanks...

Comment: `reduce` is an array method, not an object method. Did you mean `this.users.reduce((a, e) => e.amount + a, 0)`? Can you clarify what your intent is?

Comment: oh, my bad, thanks you

Comment: So did that solve the problem? If so, I'm going to vote to close as a typo.

Comment: yep, bro it solve now..